# Umbraco - Configure entity tags (ETags)

Tags: iis, umbraco

I am using Umbraco. There are three suggestion is coming when I check my performance in pingdom. I have already enabled compression in IIS Manager. But still that suggestion is coming. I don't know how to configure ETags also. Kindly let me know how to overcome this

[image: Pingdom Screenshot]

Comment: Why you not set  fewer requests? It seems that client send to many requests caused server performance down.

Comment: Is there any way to bundle all css and js? That will reduce HTTP requests. right?